# selecting element via unique id in mvc jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to select these elements via unique id. In this case unique id is `@item.cardID`.

```
@model IEnumerable<FunRanger.Models.CardModel>

foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <a name="spam" href="javascript:;" class="@item.cardID btn btn-primary">0 Spam</a>
   <a href="javascript:;" class=" @item.cardID btn btn-success">0 Loves</a>
   <a href="javascript:;" class=" @item.cardID btn btn-primary">0 Favorites</a>
   <a href="javascript:;" class=" @item.cardID btn btn-danger">0 Hates</a>
}
```

I will have many links on a view page coming via list. I tried using jQuery with each anchor tag to post some data via ajax.

I would use unique id to use an ajax action on each anchor above.

I have already used id and class with name `@item.cardID` and was using it as below before-

```
for ID- $('#'+"@item.cardID") 
for Class- $('.'+"@item.cardID")
```

Now for all left elements those should be using only unique id I have only left option is use it with the name. So I did try-

```
<a name="spam" href="javascript:;" class="@item.cardID btn btn-primary">0 Spam</a>
```

and jQuery now-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $('a[name=spam][Class="."+"@item.cardID"]').click(function () {
                alert("@item.cardID");
            });
    });
</script>
```

But this isn't working. How should I use this unique id without breaking action of other elements?

Comment: I'm not using `asp.net`. Can you tell me what is `@item.cardID`?

Comment: @Felix, It is model based id of the list that is being rendered on the page. Please consider my edited code just now.

Comment: So what is the value of `@item.cardID` after rendered to the browser?

Comment: @Felix, This is not happening. Seems jQuery code is not working for anchor element. This id is of that element which is clicked out of many elements. Is my jQuery code for this ok?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at leveraging HTML5's `data-` attributes for storing metadata on an element. jQuery supports this with the `data()` method.

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <a name="spam" data-cardId="@item.cardID" class="btn btn-primary">0 Spam</a>
   ...
}
```

Now, bind your handler to any link with a name value of "spam":

```
$(function () {
        $('a[name=spam]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cardId = $(this).data('cardId');
            alert(cardId);
        });
});
```

ref: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

ref: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/